# How to create One to one mapping(Every imageVIew with open its own alertdialog as shown in diagram) with custom views hierarchy in android?

Tags: android

I want hierarchy of views like following.

[image]

**Upto Now:-**

I do added all the imageviews added to the linear layout..and click on every imageview got position from getId.

**What i need now:-**

But I want, When i click on 1st ImageView Open 1st AlertDialog with its custom views like 8 textview and 8 togglebuttons.

Perfrom opearation on each togglebutton and textVie

**My last try like this:-**

I will open One AlertDialog on Each ImageView click and then all the ToogleButtons value like true and false in HashMap.(map.put for store).then retrive this by sharedPreffrence means when i click on toggle Its state store with preff.(map.get to get value).

**I Got from this try:-**

i am not able to fetch values properly .means if imageId==0 then AlertDialog id is also 0 and position of tb1 is change but not tb2.

Please help me!!!i was trying from last few days but didnt get.also check many links.but not match my requirement thats why i post here.

**This is my code:-**

```
int id1 = pref.getInt("id", -1);
map=new HashMap<Integer, List<Boolean>>();
ArrayList<Boolean> newList=new ArrayList<Boolean>();//This is my Arraylist
newList.add(false);//Initialise arraylist with all false values
newList.add(false);
newList.add(false);
newList.add(false);
newList.add(false);
newList.add(false);
newList.add(false);
newList.add(false);
map.put(id1,newList);
newList.set(id1,pref.getBoolean("tb_home",false));//update arralist with    preffvalues
newList.set(id1,pref.getBoolean("tb_home1",false));
//from togglebuttonclick onclick 
editor.putBoolean("tb_home", tb_newswitch_home[0].isChecked()).apply();

and update values of toogle like
int id1 = pref.getInt("id", -1);
if(id1>=0) {
tb_newswitch_home[0].setChecked(map.get(id1).get(0));
tb_newswitch_home[1].setChecked(map.get(id1).get(1));
}**//when i do this alerdialog(0) of 1st element is true and alertdialog(1) of        second element is true.**
```

Comment: Use a `ListView` or `RecyclerView`. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks @KNeerajLal for quick response..but what is reinvent wheel??sorry i am newbie so dnt knw some terms.

Comment: ok i understand the meaning..but listview for what??means for alertdialog or for imageVIew??